# Use Windows (TTF) font?

Tags: r, cairo

Is it possible to use a TTF font in R?

Is the cairo package intended for this task? How would a minimal example look like?

Comment: Ok, I just found http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html
The question can be closed.

Comment: I would suggest just answering your own question rather than closing it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an example adapted from http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html:

```
windowsFonts(Calibri=windowsFont("Calibri"))
par(family="Calibri")
plot(rnorm(1:10))
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer... (I liked the question btw...)